# Panda3D: How to configure mouse buttons for camera control?

Tags: camera, mouse, panda3d

By default, the **mouse buttons** are assigned to **camera control** as:

- Left: Translate
- Right: Zoom
- Scroll/middle: Rotate

How do I change these mouse button bindings so that I want this?:

- Scroll/middle: Zoom
- Left: Rotate
- Right: Translate

I can see that the default mouse bindings for camera control are set in `DirectCameraControl.py`. But, how can I change them from my main class which is derived from `ShowBase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera controls in `DirectCameraControl` are separate from the default controls, and changing these settings will not affect the default camera.  The default controls are hardcoded in `panda/src/tform/trackball.cxx`; it is presently not possible to change these.

The default camera controls are primarily intended for early development and debugging.  For most purposes, you'll want to use `base.disableMouse()` to disable the default camera controls and develop your own camera control code.